# Dynamically create thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I know how to use threads and background workers, but only in a "static" way (so hardcoding them). However I want to use something like this

```
public static void StartThread(string _Method)
{
    Thread t = new Thread(() => _Method;
    t.Start();
}
```

I know this will fail, due to `_Method` being a string. I've read using `delegates` but I'm not sure how this will work and if I need it in this case.

I want to start a thread for a specific function (so dynamically creating threads) when I need them.

Comment: I wonder if creating threads this way indicates a need for a thread pool?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [C# Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx) which is exactly what you need if you want to split work on different threads. Otherwise stay to Vlad's answer and use a method which accepts a delegate.

#### Task

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Console.WriteLine("Hello from taskA."));
```

#### Thread

```
public static Thread Start(Action action) {
    Thread thread = new Thread(() => { action(); });
    thread.Start();
    return thread;
}

// Usage
Thread t = Start(() => { ... });
// You can cancel or join the thread here

// Or use a method
Start(new Action(MyMethodToStart));
```

Comment: Thanks, however your code also gives me the same error as Vlad's does. `Argument 1:annot convert from 'System.Action' to 'System.Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart'` and `The best overloaded method match for 'System.Threading.Thread.Thread(System.Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart)' has some invalid arguments`.

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly! I'm starting a method like this `Utils.StartThread(() => { Utils.Debug("Hi"); });` and does the job.

Comment: you could use just `Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(action));` and avoid creating one more lambda.

Comment: @Felix: try it! And BTW you can usually omit creating an action as well: `Start(MyMethodToStart);` instead of `Start(new Action(MyMethodToStart));`

Comment: @Vlad Thats something i know, but i want to keep it clean for the reader.

Answer (score 3):

To create dynamic threads you need to create them at run time. In this example I made a method CreateThreads that creates methods and adds them to list of threads. Later I have a method StartMyThreads to start all the threads. I hope this is what you want.

```
    List<Thread> lstThreads = new List<Thread>();
    public void CreateThreads()
    {
        Thread th = new Thread(() => { MyThreadFun(); });
        lstThreads.Add(th);
    }

    private void MyThreadFun()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello");
    }

    private void StartMyThreads()
    {
        foreach (Thread th in lstThreads)
            th.Start();
    }
```

Comment: I want to create them dynamically, this can only be used with hardcoding.

Comment: i just changed the answer, have a look

Answer (score 2):

You can do this way:

```
public static void StartThread(string s)
{
    Thread t = new Thread(() => { Console.WriteLine(s); });
    t.Start();
}
```

Or, if you prefer to set the method from outside:

```
public static void StartThread(Action p)
{
    Thread t = new Thread(p);
    t.Start();
}

...
StartThread(() => { Console.WriteLine("hello world"); });
```

Edit:
Indeed, you actually need

```
public static void StartThread(Action p)
{
    Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(p));
    t.Start();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Vlad, yes I want to set it from the "outside". So using the latter code, but Visual Studio throws up two errors: `Argument 1:annot convert from 'System.Action' to 'System.Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart'` and `The best overloaded method match for 'System.Threading.Thread.Thread(System.Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart)' has some invalid arguments`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var thread = new Thread(
    (ThreadStart)delegate
        {
            Console.WriteLine("test");
        });
```

OR

```
var thread = new Thread(
    (ParameterizedThreadStart)delegate(object parameter)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(parameter);
        });
```

If you will decide to use TPL tasks please be aware that TPL uses `ThreadPool` threads so in some cases it makes difference comparing to manually created `Thread`. So read documentation and ensure you know what you do when making such a decision.

You might find this useful: [Dedicated thread or a Threadpool thread?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pedram/archive/2007/08/05/dedicated-thread-or-a-threadpool-thread.aspx)

Comment: you could just write it var thread = new Thread(() => Console.WriteLine("test")); or var thread = new Thread(parameter => Console.WriteLine(parameter)); Unless you are just being really explicit for other junior programmers to understand your code, I don't see why you would write it like that.